# Rails validate when creating multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In our Rails app we have some validation rules that ensure sure we have unique codes for an configuration that belongs to the same app when creating or editing the configuration:

```
  class Configuration < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :app
    validate :unique_code

    private

    def unique_code
      if app_codes&.include?(code)
        errors.add(code, 'is already being used for this app')
        return false
      end
      true
    end

    def app_configurations
      app&.configurations&.where&.not(id: id)
    end

    def app_codes
      app_configurations&.map(&:code)
    end
  end
```

This ensures we can't have a configuration with the same code on the same app, but we could have the same code for a configuration on another app. And works great when creating and editing the configurations on their own.

However if we create a new app and create multiple configurations at the same time (via `accepts_nested_attributes_for`) the validation doesn't capture it and lets duplicated codes through as valid... likely because the validation is comparing against 'existing' app configurations rather than the ones that are about to be created so don't exist in the DB to check against...

How can we check both scenarios? existing and the ones that are being created?

Comment: Why not to validate `accepts_nested_attributes_for :CODE :presence_of => true, :if => 'code.present?'` ?

Answer (score 1):

new method called `existing_and_new_app_codes`, which combines both the existing configurations and the new configurations that are being created for the app.

The new configurations are retrieved using `app.new_configurations.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?)`, which ensures that only the new configurations that are not marked for destruction are included in the list.

```
class Configuration < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :app
  validate :unique_code

  private

  def unique_code
    all_app_codes = existing_and_new_app_codes

    if all_app_codes.include?(code)
      errors.add(:code, 'is already being used for this app')
    end
  end

  def existing_and_new_app_codes
    existing_codes = app_codes || []
    new_codes = app.new_configurations.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).map(&:code)
    existing_codes + new_codes
  end

  def app_configurations
    app&.configurations&.where.not(id: id)
  end

  def app_codes
    app_configurations&.map(&:code)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I found that `new_configurations` raised a no method error, so ended up using: `app.configurations.reject(&:persisted?)` to get new configurations only. But this would then raise an error for itself until I changed the validator logic from: `if all_app_codes.include?(code)` to: `unless all_app_codes.detect { |e| all_app_codes.count(e) > 1 }.nil?` so that it looks for unique codes in the array that's passed.

Comment: This is because: `app&.configurations&.where.not(id: id)` prevents validating the object against itself... but for new records the id is also nil so new records will end up being compared against themselves when checking if the code is included in the passed array... so the detection of unique values seemed the cleanest.

Answer (score 0):

I kept encountering edge cases with the above solutions and discovered that Rails has a built in scope for validations for exactly this purpose:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :code, scope: :app_id
```